# mysql event doesn't work

Tags: mysql, events, information-schema

Hi I have this event stored in the event table of the information schema:

```
event_catalog:def
event_schema: m4af
event_name:aggiornaGiorni
definer:root@localhost
timezone:system
event_body:sql
event_definition:update m4af.utentibloccati set giorni=giorni+1
event_type:recurring
execute at: null
interval_value:1
interval_field:day
sql_mode:STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
starts:2012-11-26 11:40:41
ends:null
status:enabled
on_completion:not preserve
created:2012-11-26 11:40:41
last_altered:2012-11-26 11:40:41
 last_executed:2012-11-26 11:40:41
event_comment: ""
originator:0
character_set_client:utf8
collocation_connection:utf8_general_ci
database_collation:utf8_general_ci
```

Why this event does not increments the value day of my table named utentibloccati ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The events are executed by a special event scheduler thread; and it is very possible that event scheduler thread was not started. Check it using this query -

```
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;
```

The result should be - `ON`. Otherwise, execute this query to start event scheduler -

```
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

[Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

Comment: fantastic! the query returned 0 so the problem maybe is this! thanks! I hope tomorrow the value is incremented :)

Comment: You can test it today - create new event with smaller interval.

Comment: hi @Devart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400140/auto-add-field-each-user-using-event-nothing-error-and-doesnt-working please review it doesn't working, thanks