# MySQL EVENT does not execute

Tags: mysql, events, mysql-workbench

I have an event that deletes record on a table that are a month old. But it does not seem to execute.

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE EVENT delete_wykofile_back
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 YEAR
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

    DO
      BEGIN
      DELETE FROM factory.wyko_file_backup WHERE date_inserted < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

      END$

DELIMITER ;
```

What I've done so far:

- I have followed and set global event_scheduler to ON based from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679252/mysql-event-doesnt-work)
- I've also check this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38887/scheduled-event-did-not-start-when-expected), but to no avail.
- There's also no answer from this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77354/mysql-event-scheduler-doesnt-work).
- The account im using is a superuser based from [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-privileges.html).

**SHOW EVENTS;** 
[image]

**SHOW PROCESSLIST;**
[image]

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.2. I am running the event with 1 minute interval for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

needs to be the current date or a past date. Right now its set up to start on 12/4/2015.

Comment: yep, this works. i just removed the `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY`. Thanks!  nice catch! @Kevin S